locking a file accessed by concurrent processes
I need to write to and read from a config file using shell CGI, and I also have a C program that must read and modify the config file every few seconds. I tried using flock to maintain data integrity and prevent race conditions, but both CGI and C program are still able to access the file at the same time.
If I use 2 C programs on the file it works, but not both the shell CGI and C program.
This is the C program am using:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    struct flock fl = {0};
    char buff[1000];

    file = fopen("/home/siddusuhaas/sample.conf", "r+");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Opened File\n");

    // Set an exclusive lock on the entire file
    fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    fl.l_start = 0;
    fl.l_len = 0;

    if (fcntl(fileno(file), F_SETLKW, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("Error locking file");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("File Lock Successful\n");

    // Perform operations on the locked file here
    system("lslocks | grep 'bcf.conf'");

    // Read the file contents
    size_t nread = fread(buff, sizeof(char), sizeof(buff) - 1, file);
    if (nread == 0 && !feof(file)) {
        perror("Error reading file");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    buff[nread] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the buffer
    printf("Data is %zu\t %.*s\n", nread, (int)nread, buff);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        system("lslocks | grep 'bcf.conf'");
        sleep(1);
        fseek(file , 0  , SEEK_SET);
        memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
        nread = fread(buff, sizeof(char), sizeof(buff) - 1, file);
        if (nread == 0 && !feof(file)) {
            perror("Error reading file");
            fclose(file);
            return 1;
        }
        buff[nread] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the buffer
        printf("Data is %zu\t %.*s\n", nread, (int)nread, buff);
    }
    fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;
    if (fcntl(fileno(file), F_SETLK, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("Error unlocking file");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("File Unlocked Successfully\n");

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}

And this is my CGI:
#!/bin/bash

file=/home/siddusuhaas/sample.conf

exec 200>>"$file"
if ! flock -x 200; then
    echo "Unable to acquire lock on file" 
    exit 1
fi

echo "Surprise! The file is locked!" > "$file"

#Release the lock
exec 200>&-


Shouldn't you be using the flock() function?

The flock(1) program uses the flock(2) system call to lock files. Your C program is using fcntl(2) to lock files. Those are two different locking mechanisms that don't interact with each other on Linux. Change the C program to also use flock(2) locks.
I would also drop the use of stdio functions for reading and writing the file; the interaction between stdio buffering and when underlying files are actually read and written is potentially a source of subtle and hard to reproduce bugs in the presence of multiple processes modifying the same file. Keep it simple and just use open()/read()/write()/etc.

For a quick, easy, and not-so-dirty solution that doesn't require any special tools, use mkdir. See this post for a simplistic example.
mkdir is simple and atomic - if the directory doesn't exist, it makes one, and then returns a success, so you know you and only you have the lock. If it cannot do so, it returns an error, so you know you cannot get a lock right now.
With a little code you could have it wait till it can get a turn, or check for a lock older than a certain amount of time and auto-remove it, etc. This also lets you apply the same, simple logic in both bash and C.
One last suggestion - set a trap on exit to remove the lockfile.
You should always remove it explicitly as soon as possible, but accidental program exits should always clean up behind themselves as much as possible, and a lock file is a classic example of why people shouldn't blithely use kill -9 when just a simple kill would do.
